# using strings in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, substring

Hi How do I retrieve the number from the following string,

```
{"number":100,"data":[test]}
```

The number could be of any length.

I used the following code. but it gives and error message

```
strValue.Substring((strValue.IndexOf(":")+1), (strValue.IndexOf("data")));
```

the output comes like

100,"data":[

Thanks,

Comment: That looks like the start of a JSON string. Is that right?

Comment: yes. missed other bit. {"number":100,"data":test}

Comment: Look at the output of each of those function calls, see if it helps. Post the results here if you are still unsure.

Comment: @Joshua I edited your question to fix the string.  If it's wrong, let me know and I'll roll it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Jon, your input string seems to be a JSON string which needs to be deserialized. You can write your own deserializer, or use an existing library, such as [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). Here is an example:

```
string json = @"[
  {
    ""Name"": ""Product 1"",
    ""ExpiryDate"": ""\/Date(978048000000)\/"",
    ""Price"": 99.95,
    ""Sizes"": null
  },
  {
    ""Name"": ""Product 2"",
    ""ExpiryDate"": ""\/Date(1248998400000)\/"",
    ""Price"": 12.50,
    ""Sizes"": null
  }
]";

List<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json);
```

Answer (score 10):

It looks like your input string is JSON.  Is it?  If so, you should use a proper JSON parser library like [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Way to catch the underlying issue, rather than just the symptom!  I suppose I should read up on using JSON, as I keep seeing people using it.

Comment: @JonSenchyna it's got pros and cons like anything else.  Critically, it's ***much*** lighter on control characters than XML, and ECMAScript can treat it as a native object, so it's quite convenient for javascript and other ECMAScript implementations.

Comment: +1 Best approach if using JSON. Although if parsing a string in only one situation in code, the library might be a bit of unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt is close.  There are two (possibly three issues) I found.

1. Your string has a comma after the number you're looking for.  Since your code is searching for the index of "data", your end index will end up one character too far.
2. The second paramter of [String.Substring(int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) is actually a length, not an end index.
3. [Strings are immutable in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf#Immutability).  Because of this, none of the member functions on a string actually modify its value.  Instead, they return a new value.  I don't know if your code example is complete, so you may be assigning the return value of `SubString` to something, but if you're not, the end result is that `strValue` remains unchanged.

Overall, the result of your current call to `string.Substring` is returning `100,"data":[tes`. (and as far as I can see, it's not storing the result).

Try the following code:

```
string justTheNumber = null;
// Make sure we get the correct ':'
int startIndex = strValue.IndexOf("\"number\":") + 9;
// Search for the ',' that comes after "number":
int endIndex = strValue.IndexOf(',', startIndex);
int length = endIndex - startIndex;
// Note, we could potentially get an ArguementOutOfRangeException here.
// You'll want to handle cases where startPosition < 0 or length < 0.
string justTheNumber  = strValue.Substring(startIndex, length);
```

Note: This solution does not handle if `"number":` is the last entry in the list inside your string, but it should handle every other placement in it.

If your strings get more complex, you could try using [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595) to perform your searches.

Comment: If you use `strValue.IndexOf(","))`, would that return the position where the comma is? Shouldn't you pas the length of the substring you want instead? Like `strValue.IndexOf(",") - strValue.IndexOf(":")`.

Comment: That's what I get for not double-checking the OP's code for other issues aside from the first obvious one I find.  You are 100% correct.  The original code would find the string starting at ":", and the following IndexOf(",") characters.  I'll update the above right away.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing JSON spring in that way is very bad practice as everything is hardcoded. Have you though of using 3rd party library for parsing JSON strings, like [Newtonsoft JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you needed to use IndexOf(",") istead of IndexOf("data")